# Violated Residual Linearity/Homoscedasticity Assumptions in X13 Time Series Decomposition: How to Interpret and Resolve?

Tags: time-series, arima, residuals, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity

I have been working on decomposing a monthly time series of the country's exports using JDemetra+ with the X13-ARIMA-SEATS model. My aim is to break down the series into its Trend, Seasonal, and Irregular components and then perform seasonal adjustments. The objective is not forecasting, but to utilize seasonally adjusted data to identify changepoints, mainly in trend.

It is important to note that there are outliers present in the data as a result of the 2008 economic crisis and the 2020 Covid pandemic. However, manually specifying these outliers does not help much in treating autocorrelation.

The analysis went well for the most part; however, I noticed that one assumption was not fully satisfied according to the diagnostics. Specifically, the residuals' linearity/homoscedasticity were found to be violated as per the Ljung-Box on squared residuals(24) and Box-Pierce on squared residuals(24) tests.

[image]

[image]

My Questions:

1. What does it mean for my analysis when these assumptions are
   violated?
2. How might this affect the reliability of the trend, seasonal, and irregular components I have extracted?
3. Are there any remedial measures I can take to satisfy these assumptions or make my analysis more robust?

Any insights or advice would be highly appreciated!